# Using QOpenGLWidget in a window with a custom title bar causes a black rectangle on some machines

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

The goal is to have an app on Windows using `QMainWindow` with a custom-drawn title bar and containing a `QOpenGLWidget`.

Using `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` to make the title bar drawable was ruled out because of the issue described in [QTBUG-47543](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47543) - a thick white frame along the top of the window:

[image: screen-shot]

So, falling back to platform-specific Win32 `WM_NCCALCSIZE` instead...

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <windowsx.h>

class MyGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void initializeGL() override { QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions()->glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); }
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow() { setCentralWidget(new MyGLWidget); }
protected:
    bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, qintptr* result) override
    {
        MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
        switch (msg->message) {
            case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
                NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* params = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*)(msg->lParam);
                params->rgrc[0].right -= 8;  // Sizes hard-coded for brevity
                params->rgrc[0].left += 8;
                params->rgrc[0].bottom -= 8;
                *result = 0;
                return true;
            }
            // case WM_NCHITTEST omitted for brevity
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

TitleBar.pro:

```
QT += core gui openglwidgets widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

On most machines, this gives the desired result:

[image: screen-shot]

The problem that's happening on a few machines is that a completely black rectangle is showing in the area where the standard title bar would normally be:

[image: screen-shot]

Replace the `QOpenGLWidget` with a regular `QWidget` and it looks correct on all machines.

Remove `MainWindow::nativeEvent()` and set `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` on the window instead and the black rectangle problem goes away, but the above-mentioned thick white frame issue occurs instead.

<s>Why would the black rectangle problem only happen on some machines and not others?</s> (See **Edit**, below.)

Is there a way to use `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` that avoids the white frame issue, without overriding `nativeEvent()`?

If not, is there a way to handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` that works well with `QOpenGLWidget` on all machines?

Tests were done using Qt v6.2.0 on Windows 10 v21H1.

---

**Edit:**

The black rectangle goes away if `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL)` is called at the top of `main()`, implying that the problem is specific to certain OpenGL drivers.